# tmux freezes when using ctrl-prefix ctrl-y

Tags: linux, tmux

I'm using a custom .tmux.conf file which looks like this:

```
unbind-key C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix

set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection

## CLIPBOARD selection integration
# Requires prefix key before the command key
# Copy tmux paste buffer to CLIPBOARD
bind C-y run "tmux show-buffer | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
# Copy CLIPBOARD to tmux paste buffer and paste tmux paste buffer
bind C-p run "tmux set-buffer -- \"$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)\"; tmux paste-buffer"
```

I'm using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> to copy from tmux copy buffer to clipboard. But every time I do this tmux freezes and does not accept any input. I tried to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> but this doesn't help.

What can I do to prevent tmux from freezing, which shortcuts are interfering here? I also tried the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, same problem here.

Comment: please consider adding that to your question so it looks nice.

Answer (score 8):

If you type the `xclip` command on the command line you'll notice that it doesn't finish. This is because it continues to accept input until *STDIN* is done. Thus, *STDOUT* never gets closed. You can resolve this by redirecting the *STDOUT* of `xclip` to `/dev/null`. For example:

```
bind y run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -selection clipboard &>/dev/null"
```

In this example I redirect *STDERR* as well just in case it matters.

Comment: This is a very enlightening answer, but it does not solve the problem. For example, `ps aux | grep xclip` shows that the `xclip` process is still running, and continues to block the tmux terminal. Any suggestions for a command, like the one shown above, that also kills the xclip process?

Comment: Since I stumbled here, I thought I'd note that _that_ is just how the `xclip` works. It stays running even when run from command line.

The -b is the right thing to do here, otherwise tmux will attempt to wait it out, which it shouldn't do with `xclip`.

Comment: @TommiKyntola not all xclip versions have -b

Comment: @Conner Hardly any of them do afaik, the `-b` is an option to the tmux `run-shell` command.

Answer (score 3):

`xclip` is waiting for input, which blocks tmux from receiving input. The following example allows xclip to run in another shell without blocking your tmux session:

```
bind y run-shell -b "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -selection clipboard"
```

I would even add a message to help your workflow:

```
bind y run-shell -b "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -selection clipboard; tmux display-message \"Tmux buffer saved to clipboard\" "
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
bind y run-shell -b "cat << EOF | tmux save-buffer - | xclip -sel clipboard &>/dev/null"
```

you can do it this way the EOF closes the buffer after copying it to clipboard with xclip.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).